# Django : Slide bar in templates html, doesn't work with IE7

Tags: html, django, internet-explorer-7

A condition statement seems to be skipped by IE7 while working fine on every other possible browsers. IE7 hides a hyperlink (with the image going with it)
Here is the html code :

```
<a class="menu_link menu_download" {% if not download_link %}style="display:none;"{% endif %} id="menu_download_btn" href="{{download_link}}?block={{block}}">Download</a>
```

If I try to display download_link just before this statement, I got my url. Nevertheless, IE7 seems to skip my if and to run style="display:none" no matters what.

If I remove the part :

```
{% if not download_link %}style="display:none;" {% endif %}
```

my element is displayed correctly in IE7.

Any idea why this is happening this way ?

Comment: I tried to display the style tag no matters what : 

style={% if not download_link %}"display:none;" {% endif %}

It works but I have actually no idea why ...

Comment: try to run the generated code through a html validator. From what you have shown us, this should work.